# Web essential JS minification

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

Using Visual Studio Web essential 2015 for minification and bundling my JS files. But eventually occured some strange error. I've created a test example with simple code inside.

```
function foo(){
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    if(a < b)
    {
        b = a;
        b++;
    }
}
```

And as result after minification i got this:

```
function foo(){var t=1,n=2;t<n&&(n=t,n++)}
```

I can't understand, what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: What the error says. There seems to be no error.

Comment: there is no 'if' operator in minified code.

Comment: It;s there `t<n&&` means if `t` is less than `n` then do that.

Comment: That's not an error - that's the `if` condition minified away by being turned into a `&&`. The two pieces of code are exactly equivalent in functionality. Adding `if` would mean there are more characters, thus it's not as minified.